# How to choose a partition key in DynamoDB for a chat app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a requirement to use DynamoDB for a chat app that will be used occasionally, on an event day. The app will be reading/writing few thousands of messages on a particular day, and almost none after that.

Here's what I have in mind:

```
Table: Messages
HashKey: Event day name
SortKey: Message timestamp
```

I can get recent 20 messages (chat app usually get latest data only, no?), but the all read/write will be directed to one partition only.

I could try this way

```
Table: EventDayMessage
HashKey: Message timestamp
```

With this, the read/write will be spread out to the more recent message, but I have no way to get the recent messages due to no sort key.

Is method 2 better in my scenario? What can I use for the sort key? Is there any other better suggestions (other than switching db)?

Comment: When you say "will be reading/writing few thousands of messages on a particular day" what do you expect the peak number of reads/writes per second?  This makes it sound like the number will be in the single digits which means you will likely not have a hot shard problem, but if the number is in the hundreds/thousands you will want to consider a different hash key to avoid hot shard issues.

Comment: @JaredHatfield If there's no hot shard problem, method 1 is acceptable?

Comment: Yes.  The SortKey/RangeKey works well with timestamps as it is sorted and you can filter on greater than / less than to directly retrieve items efficiently.  The real risk to this approach is throttling because it will not scale well.  The other issue would be having lots of old data in the table accumulate.  Offloading older records to a different table could help with this problem though.

Answer (score 0):

my first recommendation is to move to a proper db (like elasticsearch) that answer this usage (time based search) and create a new index for each day

but if still you want to use dynamodb, a good hack can be:

- if your app write/read thousands of msges per day, so you wont get many partitions (depends also on you data size).

lets assume you are going to have 3 partitions.
your keys can be like that:

```
HashKey: Event day name + 'part_X' (where x is a number between 1-5. it can be a round rubin, or some '%' on a user_id or something like that)
SortKey: Message timestamp
```

so in your case, to get last 20 comments:
you should get 20 comments from each partition (hash = event_day_name_part_1, event_day_name_part_2 ..) and then get to top recent.