# DynamoDB - Query when hash is unknown

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm struggling to query a table because I do not know the hash key. Any advice on remodelling my table is appreciated. I have the following attributes and need to be able to retrieve the latest "processed" record where the value of "processed_at" is a unix timestamp. I also need to be able to update the attribute "processed" from 0 to 1 accordingly. Each token attribute is unique.

```
token    processed    processed_at    requested_at
u3280    1            14273587        14363965
i82gg    1            15769879        15873530
9823d    0            16838320        16967473
```

Any boffins able to help a beginner/thicko? I've seen similar issues.

Comment: what is your current table hash-range values?

Comment: I've tried a few combinations, currently token for hash and requested_at for range.

Answer (score 0):

please check the answer in here:
[How to choose a partition key in DynamoDB for a chat app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837753/how-to-choose-a-partition-key-in-dynamodb-for-a-chat-app/34837849#34837849)

some points:
you must set 'processed_at' as your range key (in order to get latest processed)
now, you need to set an hash key.
in your example there is not any good hash key that can give you a good spread over table partitions. (and a known hash key...)

so in this case, you can create a global secondary index (hash=partition, range=processed_at), where partition you need to set as some random number  (or round rubin) of X. (part_1, part_2, ... part_X)
i recommend to set X as your number of table partitions.

now, to get the latest 'processed_at' (lets assume latest 10), you need to get (10) items from each part, and then do some uniun on the result to get the actual latest (10) items..