# Get first N items sorted by a key in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I thought this would be easy but I can't figure it out.

I have a DynamoDB table where all the items have the same attributes. One of the attributes is a numeric one named `ytd`. I simply want the first 5 items sorted by `ytd`.

Comment: are they has the same hash key value?

Comment: No, it's different for each of them

Answer (score 1):

you cant do it in a simple way.
dynamo db return ordered results of the same hash key

so if your hash key here is X, and range key will be 'ytd', then in order to get 'ytd' ordered items then X should be the same.

i dont know your exactly flow, but if you are not query X (you just need to get ordered 'ytd' no matter for X), then you can add a global secondary partition with hash key=partition, range key=ytd as described here:

[How to choose a partition key in DynamoDB for a chat app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837753/how-to-choose-a-partition-key-in-dynamodb-for-a-chat-app/34837849#34837849)